# Conditional AND in awk with environment variables

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, awk

I found this command. If a line has interested word, the command will output the entire line:

```
temp="sample"
awk -F " " -v var="$temp" '$1 == var' /root/smaple.txt
```

`smaple.txt` contains:

```
sample demo 123 456
sample2 demo2 567 345
sample3 demo4 453 456
```

Now I want to check **two** values i.e. If those two values in a line, the command will output the line:

```
temp1="sample"
temp2="123"
awk -F " " -v var="$temp1" var2="$temp2" '$1 == temp1 && $3 == temp2' /root/smaple.txt
```

The expected output for my command:

```
sample demo 123 456
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused the names of the variables:

```
temp1="sample"
temp2="123"
awk -v temp1="$temp1" -v temp2="$temp2" '$1==temp1 && $3==temp2' file
```

Also the `-v` parameter has to be used multiple times, when you need multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
awk -F " " -v 'var="$temp1" var2="$temp2"' '$1 == var && $3 == var2' /root/smaple.txt
```

you were comparing with the value

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I tried with that also. It is not show any output or error